# android настройка размера изображения в теме

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk

Добрый день

Делаю  Splash Screen. В drawable создаю файл xml в котором прописываю фон и картинку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/orange"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_start"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Потом добавляю этот файл в стили:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/drawable</item>
    </style>
```

Как задать размер bitmap? Или как задать размер для logo_start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверно самый правильный вариант, это создать картинки logo_start с разными размерами и положить их в соответствующие папки:

- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi

и т.д.

Для bitmap нельзя указать размер, но можно сделать, чтобы он помещался на экране (если вы для этого хотели задать размер в dp) следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/orange"/>
    <item
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/logo_start"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

В этом случае, вокруг bitmap будет добавлен margin, а само лого по необходимости уменьшится.

UPDATE: Проблема в том, что пропорции лого изменятся, и это плохо.

Другой вариант использовать для этих целей Image View. Основной layout тогда будет таким:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/orange">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_start"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- тут могут быть другие элементы, которые откроются после скрытия FrameLayout с id=frame -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: android:left="20dp и android:right="20dp" не помогает лого все равно вылазит за рамки экрана :(

Comment: Чтобы помогло, нужно еще убрать android:gravity="center" из bitmap, но это способ тоже плохой, так как лого растягивается непропорционально. Добавил еще один способ с ImageView.